# Safari's window.history.go(index) is off by 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, browser-history

I'm trying to make a button that takes the user back two pages, but I've noticed something odd about Safari. Here is my working function:

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('.go-back').click(function(e) {
    if(jQuery.browser.safari) {
      window.history.go(-3);
    } else {
      window.history.go(-2);
    }
  });
});
```

Does anyone have an explanation for why the indexing is off by 1 in Safari?

Comment: Ok so if I add `e.preventDefault()` then Safari works as expected. Odd that only safari needs that to be added.

Comment: Is `.go-back` a hyperlink? If it is then Safari will add the clicked link href to the history and then go back thus leading to "incorrect" indexing. `e.preventDefault` will stop the link from navigating away.

Comment: @avladov yeah you're absolutely right. It seems that only Safari adds the current page to the history when clicking on a hyperlink.